react-responsive-carousel props not passing
I'm building a carousel for my portfolio using the react-responsive-carousel npm package. I'm having a hard time passing the props to the Carousel itself. I followed the examples and I'm not getting any errors but they aren't being applied. Any tips?
Thank you in advance!
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css';
<Carousel swipeable={true} showThumbs={false} stopOnHover={true} autoPlay={true} transitionTime={500} className="carousel">

I've tried changing around the props, trying to import the props directly and changing them into quotes. I'm lost.

You just have to put some elements inside the carousel as slides.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

hope it helps you
  <Carousel autoPlay={true}>
    <div>
      <img src="assets/1.jpeg" />
      <p className="legend">Legend 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="assets/2.jpeg" />
      <p className="legend">Legend 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="assets/3.jpeg" />
      <p className="legend">Legend 3</p>
    </div>
  </Carousel>

